# capacitor and electrostatic field

Tags: electrostatics, capacitance

Is there any electrostatic field around the leads of a charged capacitor? Let's take just the negative one. If I take a piece of tissue and put close to that terminal it will attract or repel the paper? And if not, why?

Answer (score 0):

Since each lead of a capacitor is connected to one of the plates, if the plates are charged then the leads will be charged, one positive and one negative. Since each of the leads has a net charge there will be an electric field associated with each lead.

Although the tissue paper is not a conductor, I should think the negative charges would have enough mobility to be repelled by the negatively charged lead leaving a net positive charge on the tissue for them to be attracted by the lead.

I haven't tried it. The attraction may be pretty weak, so you might have to tear the tissue into small bits if you want to carry out an experiment.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, this help. I think I have to charge that capacitor to high voltage to see some effect, that's why I cannot do an experiment. But how can I calculate something? Voltage vs. field strength at 1mm from the lead for example. The capacity also important?